# Unable to delete dataset because it's included in a published app - but it isn't

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to delete a dataset from one of our premium workspaces and am getting an error saying it's included in the published app. However, as you can see below, the dataset in question (Construction Daily Report) is not included in the app and no reports reference it. I also tried deleting it using PowerShell but that didn't work either. Has anyone run into this same issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have sometimes experienced significant lag between removing content from an app and republishing the app, until being allowed to actually remove the dataset from the workspace environment.

If you unpublished this very recently, simply try to wait a bit until all systems are fully up to date with currently published app contents. If a significant amount of time has passed, perhaps contact Microsoft directly.

Comment: Thanks @Marcus. The dataset in question has not been included in the app for months.

Comment: You could try unpublishing the app during off hours, and see if that «unlocks» it?

Comment: I think if I did that all my users' links would break.

Comment: I just tested this - and your app would indeed get a new GUID, so it would definitely create hassle. Is it connected to anything at all in lineage view? Reports in other apps?

Comment: According to the PBI service, nothing is dependent on this dataset.